# How to configure multileveled dynamic generated subdomains

Tags: apache, virtual, subdomain, hosts, subdirectory

I'am wondering how can i resolve that kind of problem. First of all i have directory tree looks like:

```
/var/www/sites/mydomain.com/
/var/www/sites/mydomain.com/public_html/
/var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/
/var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/user01/
/var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/user01/public_html/
/var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/user01/subdomains/
/var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/user01/subdomains/a/
/var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/user01/subdomains/b/
/var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/user01/subdomains/c/
/var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/user02/
/var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/user02/public_html/
/var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/user02/subdomains/
/var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/user02/subdomains/d/
/var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/user02/subdomains/e/
/var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/user02/subdomains/f/
/var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/user03/
/var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/user03/public_html/
/var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/user03/subdomains/
/var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/user03/subdomains/g/
/var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/user03/subdomains/h/
/var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/user03/subdomains/i/
```

I would like to ask you how can i configure my apache virtual host to change subdomains to subdirs like above tree dynamic check if directory exists and than change subdomain to subdir:

```
http://(www\.)?mydomain.com /var/www/sites/mydomain.com/public_html/
http://(www\.)?user01.mydomain.com /var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/user01/public_html/
http://(www\.)?a.user01.mydomain.com /var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/user01/subdomains/a/public_html/
etc...
```

I was trying to use VirtualDocumentRoot . 
I used

```
ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
```

and than

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/%-3/public_html/
```

and one leveled subdomain works excellent but i have no idea how to do this with second, third ... n level ?
configuring

```
ServerAlias *.*.mydomain.com
```

and

```
VirtualDocumentRoot like /var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/%-3/subdomains/%-4/public_html/
```

not giving expected result.
I'm almost sure i can do this with mod_rewrite but have no idea how?
i was trying a lot of configs but probably my knowledge is not enough.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+)\.mydomain.com\\(.*)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subdomains/(.*)?
RewriteRule (.*) /var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/%1/public_html/%2 [L]
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Can you describe in plain language what the end result should be in terms of the user experience?

Comment: I gave my friends access to my server through ftp. I decided to make a folder for each one - there are only three of them, but i wont to learn something. I suggested them to create dirs public_html and subdomains for their own pages. Than i want to point domain http://myfrienddario.mydomain.com to dir /var/www/sitest/mydomain.com/subdomains/myfrienddario/public_html/. Then i want to point their subdomains http://(.*).myfrienddadrio.mydomain.com to /var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/myfriendario/subdomains/(.*)/public_html/

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/subdomains/(.*)?
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+)\.([a-z0-9]+)\.([a-z0-9]+)\.mydomain.com(/(.*)?)?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/%3/subdomains/%2/subdomains/%1/public_html/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+)\.([a-z0-9]+)\.mydomain.com(/(.*)?)?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/%2/subdomains/%1/public_html/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+)\.mydomain.com(/(.*)?)?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/www/sites/mydomain.com/subdomains/%1/public_html/$1 [L]
```